# Convert array to JSON using keys and values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I was wondering how to convert an array to an actual JSON object with keys and values. I am creating a Node.js command-line flag parser, and I would like to transform this:

```
[ '--input', 'HI!' ]
```

to this:

```
{ "--input": "HI!" }
```

as an example. JSON.stringify will not solve this problem, as JSON.stringify gives me this:

```
["--input","HI!"]
```

which is not what I want. If there is a way to solve this problem using JSON.stringify I am still open, but to my knowledge just using JSON.stringify will not solve this problem.

Comment: What would be an expected result for the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: Does your array always have just two items?

Comment: C would be a value with a predefined key, @georg.

Comment: @MarkMeyer no it may have more

Comment: Will it always have multiples of 2 as the number of values in the array?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No, the one that would be at the end would be a value with a predefined key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to @markmeyer's answer, a for loop would be easy to read here:

```
let arr = [ '--input', 'HI!' , 'test'] 
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  if (arr[i+1] != undefined) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
  } else {
    obj["<predefinedkey>"] = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a simple `for` loop is quick and easy to read here:

```js
let arr = [ '--input', 'HI!' , 'test'] 

let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2){
  obj[arr[i]] = (arr[i+1] != undefined) ? arr[i+1] : {}
}
console.log(obj)
```

You could also do more-or-less the same thing with `reduce()`:

```js
let arr = [ '--input', 'HI!' , 'test'] 

let o = arr.reduce((obj, item, i, self) =>{
  if (i%2 == 0) 
    obj[item] = self[i+1] != undefined ? self[i+1] : {someDefault: "value"}
  
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(o)
```

Comment: Sure, @mikey, you would just replace the `{}` with your value. See edit on the second snippet.

Comment: Look at my answer -- Instead of having JSON inside of JSON, it just has it put a pre-defined key in the main JSON. Thank you for your answer- it helped me make mine!

Comment: glad it helped @Mikey.